# Robinson's Geometric Mean Test

Tags: self-study, notation, geometric-mean

I am reading [this book](https://books.google.pl/books?id=kqwn8KEKYOwC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pl#v=onepage&q&f=false):

*Ending Spam: Bayesian Content Filtering and the Art of Statistical Language Classification* by Jonathan A. Zdziarski

page 78 is about the Robinsons Geometric Mean Test.

[image: Robinson]

This is how it looks, but I don't know what $P1,\ldots,PN$ and $N$ are. I think this is word probability, but is it counted like this:

A = number of word in spam messages / number of spam messages

B = number of word in ham messages / number of ham messages

P(N) = A / (A + B)

or..?

Comment: @aeroNotAuto, please do not add the `[self-study]` tag for people. Ask them to add the tag themselves & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then there is some hope they will be familiar w/ our policy.

Comment: @gung ah, noted.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly what I have wrote, so P(N) = A / (A + B), and N is number of total mails.